# How to target the parent class from nested classes in SASS

Tags: css, sass

Is there a way to achieve something like below in SASS without indicating `.group-left` twice?

```
.wrapper .group-left {
  background-color: blue;
}
.wrapper-child:nth-child(2n+2) .group-left {
  background: red;
}
```

I was trying to put ampersand after `.group-left`, but doesn't work. So, I have to re-select `.group-left`. Below is my current code.

```
.wrapper {
  &:nth-child(2n+2) .group-left {
    background-color: red;
  }
  .group-left {
    background-color: blue;
  }
}
```

Please advise. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use parent selector and invert your nesting in sass

```
.group-left {
  .wrapper & {
    background-color: blue;
  }
  .wrapper-child:nth-child(2n+2) & {
    background: red;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
.wrapper {
    .group-left {
        background-color: blue;
    }
}
.wrapper-child {
    &:nth-child(2n+2) {
        .group-left {
            background: red;
        }
    }
}
```